# Identify these diodes?

Tags: diodes, identification

I recently bought assorted diodes from [here](http://www.goldmine-elec-products.com/prodinfo.asp?number=G4006), and I'm having trouble identifying part of a reel of diodes. I've taken a few pictures [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ugvCb.jpg).

[image: Diodes]

The ruler is in centimeters. The diode markings are all along the diode horizontally. They appear as follows:

(M)K

D35

-20

-08

408

Anyone have any idea what part number they are and if possible a datasheet location? Thanks.

Comment: http://www.americanmicrosemi.com/information/spec/?ss_pn=D35

Answer (score 1):

This probably is a DIAC D35 manufactured by Motorola.

Datasheet:
http://www.datasheetarchive.com/indexer.php?file=Scans-0015363.pdf&dir=Scans-000&keywords=DIAC+100%2F03&database=user-highscore#

Comment: Thanks. Any idea how I could confirm the identity of these diodes?

Comment: Testing diac [article](http://androiderode.com/entries/blog/how-to-test-diac#.UQLWk33M7UI)